# How can I change an input to be disabled using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an input looking like this:

```
<input type="text" value="1.1" size="5" name="Topic" id="Topic">
```

What's the best way to change it so this input is disabled using jQuery?

**Update**

Sorry I forgot to ask but is there also a way that I can make it read only. The original answers are great but this is just one more thing I need to be able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery >= 1.6:

```
$("#Topic").prop("disabled", true);
```

jQuery < 1.6:

```
$("#Topic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Is setting prop a new way to set attributes. I didn't see this before. Also I'm sorry I forgot to ask. Is there also a way that I can make it read-only?

Comment: You can do the same thing, but with `"readonly"` instead of `"disabled"`. Yes, `.prop()` sets dynamic properties, whereas `.attr()` sets attributes, which are read only once at page load time. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute `disabled="disabled"`:

```
$("input#Topic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have to set the disabled attribute:

```
$('#myinput').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To re-enable it, you can:

```
$('#myinput').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there also a way that I can make it read-only? I am not sure but I want to get my form values back. If it is disabled will the values be returned?